# Modify the socket timeout for elasticsearch bulk requests only

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Greetings stackoverflowers! I'm currently bumping into an issue with our elasticsearch re-index functionality. I'm using `spring-data-elasticsearch` 7.10.0 and I created an elastic template class to do my bulk indexing using Java. Basically I create a list of index queries and I try to index the given elasticsearch index using the provided method below from elasticsearch:

```java
@Override
    public final List<IndexedObjectInformation> bulkIndex(List<IndexQuery> queries, BulkOptions bulkOptions,
            IndexCoordinates index) {

        Assert.notNull(queries, "List of IndexQuery must not be null");
        Assert.notNull(bulkOptions, "BulkOptions must not be null");

        return bulkOperation(queries, bulkOptions, index);
    }
```

How ever, when I try to import and index large batches of data (stream of around 10GB data). I get the following error:

```
Error while processing event: 60,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-3244 [ACTIVE]; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: 60,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-3244 [ACTIVE]
```

**Properties:**

I do the batching 200 index queries per bulk request without concurence.

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    elasticsearch:
      max-connection-idle-time: 15000 # 15 seconds
      read-timeout: 7000 # 7 seconds
      socket-timeout: 60000 # 60 seconds
      connection-timeout: 4000 # 4 seconds
```

As you can see my socket timeout is 60 seconds (it shows it in the error as well). This configuration works most of the time but rarely I get the socket timeout exception. Bumping the socket-timeout fixes the issue but I wanted to know if there is a way to bump it only for the bulk indexing requests and not all of them including read requests?

**What I tried:**

I tried modifying the passed `BulkOptions` by setting the timeout to 20 minutes. After I tried to reindex a large file I got the same socket-timout exception showing 60 seconds. Is there a way to apply different socket-timeout to bulk index queries only? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The timeout value from the `BulkOptions` parameter has nothing to do with the network layer, it is sent as a parameter in the query to Elasticsearch, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk-api-query-params.

Spring Data Elasticsearch does not support changing the network timeout settings per request or request type.

Comment: I see. I will try a retry mechanism along with a socket timeout bump if needed. Thank you for the answer!